# Derivatives of definite integrals

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

My textbook has two problems: $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_2\sin(t^2)dt$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^{\cos(x)}_0e^{t^2}dt$$

It says that the first derivative is (obviously) equal to $\sin(x^2)$ and then gives the more complicated answer to the latter as $-\sin(x)e^{\cos^2(x)}$

How should I interpret problems such as these and how should I go about trying to solve them? Why is only $x$ considered in the first derivative and not $2$ also, and how do they arrive at the second answer?

Comment: I suppose it is $d/dx$ instead of $d/dt$ ...

Please also use \sin and \cos to type the trigonometric functions

Comment: The second one uses the chain rule, since the upper bound is a function of $x$ and not $x$

Comment: Leibniz’s rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both integrals should be differentiated by $x$ and not by $t$. With this in mind:

We know from the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) that if
$$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \ dt$$

and $f(x)$ is continuous over $[a,b]$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.

Take a look at the first integral. Let it equal the function $G(x)$. We're being asked to find

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_2^x \sin(t^2) \ dt = G'(x)$$

Since $F'(x)=f(x)$ as previously stated, this gives us

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_2^x \sin(t^2) \ dt = G'(x)=\sin(x^2)$$

For the second integral, it is the **chain rule** that gives you the seemingly complicated answer. This is because instead of $x$ as the upper bound, we have the *function* $\cos x$. Therefore we will let $u=\cos x$ and define the second integral as $H(u)$:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\cos x} e^{t^2} \ dt = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{u} e^{t^2} \ dt = \frac{d}{dx}H(u)$$

Recall from the chain rule that

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}$$

So now we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}H(u) &= \frac{dH}{du} \frac{du}{dx} \\
&= e^{\cos^2 x} \frac{du}{dx} \ \text{(FTC)} \\
&= -\sin(x)e^{\cos^2 x}
\end{align}
$$

as required.

Answer (score 2):

Let there be a function $F$ such that $F' = e^{(t^2)}$.

Then the form of the definite integral will be $F(\cos(x)) - F(0)$.

Then you take the derivative of this: $F'(\cos(x))\times \cos'(x)$.

Then you apply the definition of $F'$:$\space\space$ $e^{(\cos^2(x))}\times-\sin(x)$.

$\blacksquare$